# Injecting an external dependency to Protobuf?

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

I have a class hierarchy of Protobufs that are serialized and deserialized.  Now in run-time I'd like one of these classes to contains an instance of my class which is implemented by me in C++ and contains some kind of decoration and caches I find out in run-time.
Is there a way to implement this with just the normal protobuf compiler?

Two options I though of is using an index with an integer id for every instance of the class. I'd like to avoid this due to the performance hit.
Another option is to mangle the generated source files with an external script. This is rather ugly and I'd also like to avoid it if possible.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what you're trying to do? Are you using the protobuf generated classes throughout your app? Normally one would convert them to proper domain objects (or at least wrap them); the use of the data transfer objects should be localised.

Answer (score 0):

Generate a .proto at runtime to describe your decorated message, invoke protoc to get a descriptor, and then use a DynamicMessage?

A bit messy, but it might just work. See [Self-Describing Messages](http://code.google.com/apis/protocolbuffers/docs/techniques.html#self-description) in the protobuf documentation.

Comment: The decoration cannot be represented as a protobuf message. It's a simple C++ class.